# Error synchronizing remote to local directory using spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

I have have the next error:

ERROR com...ErrorHandler  - receiving error response with null parametter org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: Problem occurred while synchronizing remote to local directory

with spring integration 2.2.6, I am using an inbound-channel-adapter with the next configuration:

```
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInbound"
    channel="sftpInboundChannel" session-factory="sftpClientFactory"
    auto-startup="true" filename-pattern="*.csv"
    auto-create-local-directory="true" delete-remote-files="true"
    remote-directory="${ftp.remoteInputDirectory}" local-directory="${ftp.localTempFolder}">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" />
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

This error occurs randomly. If someone know why this could be happening or maybe if is something in the configuration above.

Comment: Please show the complete stack trace.